# ALB access logs request initiator domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, access-log, aws-alb

is there any way to retrieve the user client domain from the ALB access logs?
from AWS documantation there is a 'domain_name' attribute but it is indicates the requested server domain rather than the client domain.

i know that in nginx there is a domain attribute which indicates the domain of the client,
is there a way to retrieve client domain from the alb?.

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, ALB [access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-log-entry-format) **do not provide client's dns name**. Instead they return:

- client:port - The IP address and port of the requesting client.

Thus, to get the domain name of the client, you would have to **parse the logs**, and "manually" get the domain based on the IP. For example, if python is used, there is [gethostbyaddr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) which can be useful in getting the domain name from an IP address.